# Animate jQuery UI dialog auto resize

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog with a dynamic form inside that can increase the height of the dialog. `autoResize` is set to true, `width` is 500.  Is there any way to animate the dialog resize when more content is added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally I was using `.show('fade')` and the size of the dialog would jump whenever `.show` was called.  When using the effect `.show('fast')` or `.show('slow')`, the dialog is resized in a sliding fashion which works for me.

Answer (score 16):

**Animating** dialog size, while staying in the **center** of the screen

```
jQuery("#dialog").dialog("widget").animate({
    width: '400px', 
    height: '110px'
  }, {
  duration: 500,
  step: function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
  }
});
```

Comment: when done resizing/enlarging, when I add new content via html( ) my content is cropped to the height of the previous size...

Answer (score 1):

When i was using @Steven's answer i have issues with content size, like @jedierikb said in comment. So i created this code and it works.

```
$(dialogSel).dialog("widget").animate({
    width: 100,
    height: 200
}, {
    duration: 200,
    step: function (now, tween) {
        if (tween.prop == "width") {
            $(dialogSel).dialog("option", "width", now);
        } else {
            $(dialogSel).dialog("option", "height", now);
        }
    }
});
```