# jQueryUI dialog cropping content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqga3/) which demonstrates the problem.

First I display a jQueryUI dialog with a fixed size.  Then I enlarge it [via an animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875270/animate-jquery-ui-dialog-auto-resize) to a new fixed size.  Then I add new content to the dialog.  The new content is being cropped by the height of the original dialog window.  Alas, my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756325/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-ui-dialog-automatically-grow-or-shrink-to-fit-its-conten) on how to fix this is coming up blank.

```
$(function() {
  var dg = $("#dialog");
  dg.dialog( {
        height: 200,
        width: 80,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: 'center'
  });

 dg.dialog("widget").animate({
        width: '400px',
        height: '400px'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function() {
            dg.dialog('option', 'position', 'center' );
        },
  complete: function( evt ) {
  //big --> font-size: 200px;
  dg.html( "<span class='big'>YA!</span>" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Width and Height of the underlying DOM element in the complete handler appears to fix the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/SyCu2/

e.g.

```
complete: function( evt ) {
      dg.width(400).height(400);
      dg.html( "<span class='big'>YA!</span>" );
      }
```

Comment: Okay, got it. But what about this?  http://jsfiddle.net/cwu7A/  What is the correct size for the inner content?

Comment: You can read the correct height off of the Dom element. See http://jsfiddle.net/sh25K/

Answer (score 0):

Use `minHeight` instead of `height`. http://jsfiddle.net/kGJbj/